# Checkout page take too much time to load

Tags: checkout, magento2.3

On my magento 2.3 website when i go to checkout page, it take too much time to load. It goes to infinite loading and does not display anything.
see https://prnt.sc/ph91kn
Please help how to solve this issue.
I am loosing customers because of this.

Comment: Check any module 3rd party module you installed which makes checkout page loading

Comment: check logs - debug log and or exception log

Comment: @ArshadSyed how can i solve with the third party module. I need all the modules.

Comment: what error it is giving in logs and if you don't find it, Just check the modules related to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove generated/code/* and var/cache/*

> rm -rf generated/code/* var/cache/*

Second, Clean the cache

> php bin/magento cache:clean

Third, Change the file permission

> sudo chmod 777 -R generated/ var/ pub/

Fourth, run Generated Compile the code

> php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Tried this, This works for sometime ,but again same issue arises.